# Scheduled process stops working after several executions

Tags: java, multithreading, rsync

I have a program running on a linux machine. That program has a class, that schedules a thread for execution every minute. The thread supposed to perform several calculations, create a text file and then synchronize the file to a different machine using `rsync`.

The class looks like this:

```
public class Generator {

    private ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor SchEventPool = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);

public void generate() {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
        int delay = 60 - ldt.getSecond();

        SchEventPool.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new HelperClass(), delay, 60, SECONDS);
    }

private class HelperClass implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // some calculations
            // .
            // . 
            // .
            FileBuild();        
        }

        private void FileBuild(){
            try{
                String filepath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/SomeDir/somefile.txt";
                File f = new File;
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                      writer.write("write something into the file" + "\n");
                }
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
            // synchronize the file
            synchronize();
        }

        public void synchronize(){
        try {
            String[] cmd = new String[]{"rsync", "--remove-source-files", "-avre", "/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa", "/home/user/project/SomeDir,                                     "user@server.ip:/home/user/project/AnotherDir/"};
            Process p = new ProcessBuilder().command(cmd).start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    }

}
```

When i run the main program and invoke the `generate()` method, the process runs successfully for about 30 minutes, sometimes more sometimes less, and then the execution of the scheduled thread stops. Without any errors or any warnings.
I should mention that the file that is being synchronized to the second machine is about 1500 KB, very small file.
I have also monitored the processors load during running and business as usual, server is not overloaded.

What could be the issue here?
Why would the scheduled thread stops being executed?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38098494/why-processbuilder-in-java-hangs-after-5-mins

Comment: I'll give it a try. Although i think i tried it already.

Comment: @MarianP di not help. It run for about 25 minutes and froze.

Comment: I would suggest you to add logging and make a thread dump of blocked program.